# ReactJS axios post corse issue

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios for post request.I am getting an error no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

```
const apiUrl = `${this._url}/${route}`
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'JWT token' 
}
return  axios.post(apiUrl,data,headers)
```

But If I use params like below code It will work.

`const _header={
      headers: { 
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'post',
      url: apiUrl,
      params:data
    }
   axios(headers)`
 
 I want to use data insated of params.

Comment: This is likely an issue with your backend. What do you use there? How do you parse the JWT? Are you allowing CORS on your REST controller?

Comment: Yes I allowing CORS on my REST. It's axios issue. It does not work since it serializes the object to JSON and it all comes through as a single parameter.

Comment: Are you sure your backend is returning cors headers when it fails with 5XX or 4XX errors ?

Comment: I have solved the problem using this code base  `const _data= qs.stringify(data)
return axios.post(route,_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead. you can encode data using the qs library. It will work fine.

```
import qs from 'qs'
const _data= qs.stringify(data)
return axios.post(route,_data)
```